# Get variable by name

Tags: python, class

How do I get a saved value from the 'self' syntax, using a variable as 'key'?

**Some code:**

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, n1, n2, n3, ...):
        self.node_1 = n1
        self.node_2 = n2
        self.node_3 = n3

        ...
    def get_node(n):
        return self."node_"+n  # This is wrong. What should I use?
```

1. I can't do a switch statement, because I have 21 values...
2. Just to make it extra clear, if `n = 2`, I want the value `self.node_2`. So `n = 3` is `self.node_3`, etc.

Comment: Why don't you just have a `self.nodes` list? While you *can* access attributes by a name stored in a string, a list of nodes would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Ad-hoc solution? `getattr` function. Correct solution, as always for "I need a dynamic variable names" is to use a dict (if names has to be really arbitrary) or a list (if you want var1, var2, ... varN).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getattr(class_obj, 'property')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr). On passing the class's object, and property to access as `string`, you will get the value of the corresponding property . Below is the sample code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, n1, n2):
        self.node_1 = n1
        self.node_2 = n2

    def get_node(self, n):
        return getattr(self, n)

x = MyClass('value_1', 'value_2')

print x.get_node('node_1')
# Output: 'value_1'
```

However you should also update your `__init__()` method to to use `**args` as you mentioned you have huge list of properties. Use [`setattr(class_obj, 'property', value)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) along with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to dynamically set properties. Below is the example for that:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self, *args):
...         for i, item in enumerate(args):
...             setattr(self, 'node_{}'.format(i+1), item)
...     def get_node(self, n):
...         return getattr(self, n)
... 
>>> x = MyClass(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> x.get_node('node_1')
1
>>> x = MyClass('a')
>>> x.get_node('node_1')
'a'
```